# GIT local branches

Tags: git, tfs

As GIT is decentralised , i understand that developer can create a local feature branch and commit to this local branch . He/she will be able to continue working  even when there is no internet connection.

In such cases , if the developer machine crashes , does it mean the complete local branch is lost ?

Having the ability to create a local branch is cited as major benefit of GIT . But if the local branch cannot withstand developer machine crashes , then i dont see a beneift.

Is there any other benefit of the decentralized nature of GIT ?

Comment: Nothing local can ever (unless the disk can be salvaged) survive a machine crash. Push the dev branch to central repo to save it. That does require an internet connection though.

Comment: The combination of false premises and blinkers is off-topic in civilized society.

Answer (score 1):

A *branch* in git is a a pointer to a snapshot of your repository. The data that belongs to this snapshot is persisted on a hard-drive, in gits database for that repository (`.git` folder) and as files (`git checkout`).

This branch can exist in your local repository but *also* on other remotes. Whether or not you want to share/backup your branch/pointer is entirely up to you. If your hard-drive crashes without having shared the branch (and the objects that belong to it) then you are out of luck, but this is no different from other version control systems.

The main difference is that git *allows* you to have repositories on your hard-drive that you can *choose* to not share.

Comment: Then what is the use of decentralized nature of GIT

Comment: That you can enjoy the strengths of having  branches with history during development.